# Android: Hide sqlite errors from trace

Tags: sqlite, logging

Sometimes I get stack traces with sql error logs. I dont want my database logic visible to the user. Is it possible to prevent loging of sqlite errors in case of an sql error?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use **insertOrThrow** and surround your code in a **try catch** block

Reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29

Comment: -1: This doesn't work. I am using `insertOrThrow` and handling the errors appropriately, but it still reports errors in the logcat.

Comment: You will still get a SQLiteLog error trace, but you won't get a full stack trace with SQLiteDatabase log tag. That's a little better but there doesn't seem to be any better as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195357/disable-sqlitelog-in-android