# Disable SQLiteLog in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm new with managing dbs in Android and i would like to know how can I disable the SQLiteLog stack trace.

I'm using this to prevent duplicates rows:

```
long id = mDatabase.insertOrThrow(MYTABLE, null,
        values);
```

In my logcat I can see many lines like that:

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (2067) abort at 21 in [INSERT INTO etc etc
```

Is there a way to disable this?

I also tried this with no luck:

```
try {
    long id = mDatabase.insertOrThrow(MYTABLE, null,
                values);
} catch (SQLException ignored) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a system message you can´t disable it.

Try filtering the messages in your Eclipse´s [**`LogCat`**](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#logcat), for example:

1) by tag:

2) by Severity:

[image]